# JDBC - Cannot Connect to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to my database but my try/catch keeps on receiving an error. This is my first time trying to connect with JDBC. I am not sure what I am doing wrong as I was just following a tutorial.

Code:

```
import java.sql.*;


public class jdbc {

    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Connection conn = null;

        try
        {
            String userName = "root";
            String password = "";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apple";
            Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance ();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection (url, userName, password);
            System.out.println ("Database connection established");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.err.println ("Cannot connect to database server");
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    conn.close ();
                    System.out.println ("Database connection terminated");
                }
                catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://img833.imageshack.us/img833/604/databaseproblem.jpg

Comment: Add e.printStackTrace() to your catch block. That will make it easier to debug the issue.

Comment: You'll never find out until you post the exception's own message stack trace. Never substitute your own message: always print or log the actual exception class and message and in severe cases the stack trace.

Comment: can you post your stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

To obtain a proper stacktrace, remove the first catch block in your method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        String userName = "root";
        String password = "";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/apple";
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
        System.out.println("Database connection established");
    } finally {
        if (conn != null) {
            try {
                conn.close();
                System.out.println("Database connection terminated");
            } catch (Exception e) { /* ignore close errors */ }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you will find out the nature of the error. You will also need to ensure the mysql-connector.jar is on your classpath. This jar contains the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class you are using to connect.

Answer (score 0):

After looking above code which is correct, it seems that there are number of possibilties for exception.

1. Check mysql driver jar is available in build/class path.
2. Check mysql has been installed correctly.
3. Check mysql username/password.
4. Check mysql port.

Answer (score 0):

had the same issue, two things solved my problem:

```
You must remember to put your JDBC connection code in an AsyncTask, other wise you will BURN BURN BURN!

Do NOT mistake "INTERNET" permission for the "uses INTERNET" permission. You need the latter to perform JDBC.
```

If none of above solved your problem, check the logcat line starting with "caused by:" in your warning lines. Googling that line gets you close to finding a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this for quite a while. I could not connect to a local Mysql using JDBC with a very basic setup. It was driving me crazy.

Added the server timezone fixed the issue.

serverTimezone=UTC

My final connection string was

jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/testdb?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC

Hope this helps someone out there